# SQL Report Builder 3.0 - Invoice Like Report with total at bottom (multi page)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, reporting

I am just wondering if anyone knows how I can set some data to be put at the bottom of a multi-page report (not in the footer) or in the footer and it to be only included on the last page if the document is a multi-page report lets say?

thanks for any help or being pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out its really simple, right click on the footer of the page and select properties.. then untick "Print on first page" and there you have it, it only appears on the last document of a multi-page report

[image]